# "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html."

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari, http-headers

Sorry if this is actual duplicate but I haven't managed to find answer for my problem.

I load the script with jQuery's $.getScript. But it causes the following error:

> Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.

The problem appears only in Safari under Mac OS

If to look on headers received from the server, they contain `Content-Type:application/x-javascript`, so I really don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, but unluckily I cannot get you link:(

Comment: Could you recreate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can better follow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: **[Chrome says “Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.”, what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)**

Answer (score 9):

> Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.

Technically that's not an error but a notice / warning and should not cause any issues in particular; if anything it's a good indication that some browsers may choose to ignore such a response.

The correct `Content-Type` response header for JavaScript according to the [RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) is:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Previous values of `text/javascript` and `application/x-javascript` are either obsolete or deprecated respectively; that said, IE <= 8 will only accept the former so be careful when making any changes to your documents.

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue and it was caused by *Web.Config* authorization block, I had to add an entry in *Web.Config* to make this script available also when not logged in:

```
<location path="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: In my case, when I added ASP authorization login modules to my project, suddenly I get this error. Adding this block to my web.config, fixed the error. Thanks!