# .htaccess AddType does not work

Tags: javascript, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created .htaccess file for the urlrewrite of the site that I'm working. After adding .htaccess it stopped loading JavaScript s and CSS s. So I then added `AddType text/css .css` and `AddType text/javascript .js`. But I get the same error. Following is my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteBase /downsouthlk.comV3/
RewriteEngine On

AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js

#Turn on the rewriting engine 

RewriteRule ^admin/dash/?$ /admin/dash.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/addcity/?$ /admin/addCity.php [NC,L]


</IfModule>
```

This is the error that I get from chrome developer options:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
> text/html
>
> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
> text/html

Comment: What URL are you using to test this? What happens when you comment out both `AddType` lines?

Comment: http://folderonLAN/admin/dash/

When I comment them same happens. Missing css and js.

Comment: ok can you tell few css/js URLs causing 404 for you?

Comment: "http://melani/ceynet/downsouthlk.com%20-%20V3/admin/dash/assets/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is use of relative links in your css/js links. Make sure to use  absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

OR else you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the server to send a JavaScript response with

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: No, when you include a javascript file in the html, use application/javascript instead of text/javscript. Maybe you have to change the .htaccess file also.

Comment: I did that. Both html and .htaccess. sry but still the same.

Comment: I found a same issue on this page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349939/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html

Answer (score 0):

Use AddHandler

```
AddHandler text/css .css
AddType text/css .css

AddHandler text/javascript .js
AddType text/javascript .js
```