# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html coldfusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, coldfusion

The problem. After calling a Coldfusion Componet method I receive the following message: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html. This was not an issue a couple of days ago. I am calling other methods associated with this component and am getting the desire result. When I actually run the method directly on the coldfusion server I get the response I am expecting in the format I am expecting. There seems to be some unwanted translation going on somewhere.

Here is the $.ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "jsonp",
 cache: false,
 data: calculate_radius(),
 url: "components/components.cfc?method=tester",

success: function(response) {

},
error: function(response) {
 console.log(response);
 var response_data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
 images = response_data;
}
})
}
```

Here is the Coldfusion method:

```
<cffunction name="tester" access="remote" retunformat="json">
    <cfset test = 'random text to send back'>
    <cfreturn test>
  </cffunction>
```

I am really stumped here can someone please help. Sorry for the localhost link, that's the only way I can work through this thing until I am able to get it hosted on a web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3467404/1636917 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5349939/1636917

Comment: Is it a CF error message you are getting?

Comment: I just fixed the issue, however it raises another question. I was pointing to 192.168.x.x:8500 and this when I had my issue described above. However, when I changed to localhost:8500 the issue went away. Would this be the way I have the web server configured causing the issue? Thanks!

Comment: What CF version are you using?

Comment: @FrankTudor Coldfusion 10

Comment: @ScottStroz No. It seemed like a client message. When i change from IP address to localhost, the issue goes away.