# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

With Chrome 12.0.742.112, if I redirect with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Location: http://0.0.0.0:3000/files/download.zip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Runtime: 0.157964
Content-Length: 0
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18)
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2011 18:42:25 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Which if followed returns the following header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Jul 2011 18:18:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Length: 150014
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18)
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2011 18:44:47 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Chrome will not redirect, nor change the previous page, it'll just report the following warning in the console:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip.

The process works correctly in Firefox, and also works fine in Chrome if I open a new tab and go directly to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/files/download.zip`. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug/quirk of Chrome?

Comment: Related: [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3467404)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've fixed this…by simply opening a new tab.

Why it wasn't working I'm not entirely sure, but it could have something to do with how Chrome deals with multiple downloads on a page, perhaps it thought they were spam and just ignored them.

Comment: What do you mean you "opened a new tab"??? You manually opened a new browser window and pasted the download URL in there?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I assumed it was a bug in the application-state of the particular tab.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the user to open a new tab... And I don't find opening one to download a file elegant either.

Comment: I had the same problem, I do not open a new tab for the download, but closed and reopened the tab with the download link. Pretty sneaky.

Comment: @joram - window.open creates a pop-over window which gets blocked by browsers. This isn't an effective solution for file downloads. Window.location.assign('') is a better solution.

Comment: @Joram et. al.  - opening a tab for a download (using target '_blank') - does not solve the problem, it just transfers the "Resource intrepreted as Document" console warning message to a new tab. Sweeping under the rug is not s solution.

Comment: This clearly does not solve the original answer. Seriously... What would I put in the user doc "copy the url, open a new tab, paste the url, ..."? Business down.

Comment: @StrandedKid If I remember correctly, opening a new tab fixed the issue permanently, I wasn't able to recreate it after that.

Comment: Read @colminator comments right upon there, opening in a new tab does not fix anything, and never did.

Comment: @StrandedKid It did for me. When I say I opened a new tab, I went to the original page and clicked download, and it worked as expected, not that I pasted the file URL into a new tab. If you'd like to speculate why that could be the case I'd love to hear it...it certainly puzzled me at the time!

Comment: Awesome works. Just add target="_blank" in your a tag

Comment: window.open('http://example.com/archive.zip', '_blank');  workes fine,in my case it shows save popup box in chrome

Comment: By adding  target="_blank" to the link, that will then work without having to specify the "download" attribute like in the other answer.

Comment: This problem occurred to me when I got a message about not allowing the page to download multiple documents.

Answer (score 178):

You can specify the HTML5 **download** attribute in your <a> tag.

```
<a href="http://example.com/archive.zip" download>Export</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: "download" attribute is not support in ie or some other browser. if you have a other options please help me

Comment: That fixes Chrome, but breaks other browsers. My Android phones won't download from that kind of link.

Comment: sigh. **THIS 'FIX' DOES NOT WORK FOR MOST BROWSERS** - only Chrome. And it's 2016, so don't expect it to anytime soon either.

Comment: problem with this is actually you can't use it in a system where you want only logging in user to download the file and generate a user-specific link for your downloads.

Comment: It's a pity this doesn't apply to forms, so you could POST form contents and have it result in a file download without Chrome complaining about this warning.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference in Chrome 2019

Comment: @all It's 2035 (I've come from future) and there is no computer to support this.

Comment: iOS does not support it and now its 2019 - so nope and nope. https://caniuse.com/#search=download (@Brian)

Comment: That caniuse.com link actually shows that browser support is very good these days, all things considered. Seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: @AliFarhoudi Now that the majority support it as of the year of 2020, let’s see….

Comment: By the way Chrome seemingly does not suppress the warning if the resource to download does not have the same _origin_.

Comment: this wont work if you trigger the download via `window.location.assign('download-zip?filename=' + filename)` and not the anchor link, for instance i click a button to send an ajax call to zip selected files for download and once all are zipped the ajax response function will trigger the download using the above javascript , and it would throw the warning in the console

Comment: This is a link. And you could/should put the link in a form. If you use form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data", you will not get the dreadful error. Example: <form method="get" action="http://example.com/archive.zip" enctype="multipart/form-data"><a href="#" onclick="this.closest(\'form\').submit();return false;" target="_blank">download</a></form>

Answer (score 36):

In your request header, you have sent `Content-Type: text/html` which means that you'd like to interpret the response as HTML. Now if even server send you PDF files, your browser tries to understand it as HTML. That's the problem. I'm searching to see what the reason could be. :)

Comment: I've tried sending it as `Content-Type: application/zip` with no avail, it still tries to process it as a 'Document'. It's probably also worth pointing out that the zip URL is dynamic in my app, so it's nothing to do with caching.

Comment: Thanks! Could it be something to do with Chrome sending the `Accept` request header as `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`, perhaps? I'm absolutely stumped here, I really am!

Comment: No, in `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` there is a part which says that Chrome accepts almost everything (`*/*`).

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no request header in the question. Both of them are response headers.

Comment: And why is the browser so stupid to request `text/html` when this will be a PDF? I didn't tell text/html anywhere to the browser.

Comment: And I am sitting here wondering why this should be an answer but not a comment ?

Answer (score 27):

I could not find anywhere just an *explanation* of the message by itself. Here is my interpretation.

As far as I understand, Chrome was expecting some material it could possibly display (a *document*), but it obtained something it could not display (or something it was told not to display).

This is both a question of how the document was declared at the HTML page level in `href` (see the `download` attribute in Roy's message) and how it is declared within the server's answer by the means of HTTP headers (in particular `Content-Disposition`). This is a question of *contract*, as opposed to hope and expectation.

To continue on Evan's way, I've experienced that:

```
Content-type: application/pdf
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=some.pdf
```

is **just inconsistent** with:

```
<a href='some.pdf'>
```

Chrome will cry **Resource interpreted as document but transferred…**

Actually, the *attachment* disposition just means this: the browser shall not interpret the link, but rather store it somewhere for other—hidden—purposes. Here above, either `download` is missing beside `href`, or `Content-disposition` must be removed from the headers. It depends on whether we want the browser to render the document or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 26):

I experienced this problem when serving up a PDF file (MIME type application/pdf) and solved it by setting the Content-Disposition header, e.g.:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.pdf
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: but where to write this ?

Comment: @coder You add headers like this from your webserver. Not sure what you are using for that, so it's hard to give more info. What language or framework are you using for your server?

Comment: Have this in our headers but Chrome still throws the warning

Comment: nopes it does not fix anything on chrome Version **76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)** i already have the headers attached

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue when performing a file download through Javascript. Adding the download attribute made no difference but adding target='_blank' did - I no longer get the 'Resource interpreted as Document...' console message.

Here's my nicely simple code:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.target = '_blank';
link.href = url;
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for Firefox
link.click();
link.remove();
```

I haven't tried it with direct HTML but would expect it to work.

Note I discovered that Firefox requires the link to be appended to the document whereas Chrome will work without it.

Comment: just a warning, a target = '_blank' will trigger IE 11's popup prevention mechanism...

Comment: FYI, I did test it with direct HTML in Chrome (Version 87.0.4280.141, 64-bit) and it did not work.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this same issue today with Chrome Version 30.0.1599.66 with my node.js / express.js application.

The headers *are* correct, express sets them properly automatically, it works in other browsers as indicated, putting html 5 'download' attribute does not resolve, what *did* resolve it is going into the chrome advanced settings and checking the box "Ask where to save each file before downloading".

After that there was no "Resource interpreted as document...." error reported as in the title of this issue so it appears that *our* server code is correct, it's Chrome that is incorrectly reporting that error in the console when it's set to save files to a location automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this when I assigned src="image_url" in an iframe.
It seems that iframe interprets it as a document but it is not. That's why it displays a warning.

Comment: could you please say me how did you fixed it?
as i m facing the same problem here when using an iframe

Comment: I used form data:

`var photoData = new FormData();`

and then set the property

`contentType: false` in my ajax request.

The post request will be: `Content-Disposition: form-data;`
And the content-type `Content-Type: text/html`

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by `adding target="_blank"` to the link.
With this, chrome opens a new tab and loads the PDF without warning even in responsive mode.

Comment: I did this and it worked: `window.open(href, '_blank');` and the new tab auto closes after the download.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this and none of the other information I could find helped: it was a stupid error: I was sending output to the browser before starting the file download. Surprisingly, I found no helpful errors found (like "headers already sent" etc.). Hopefully, this saves someone else some grief!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in an ASP web site project.  Adding a "Content-Length" header caused downloads to start working again in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was re-appeared at Chrome 61 version. But it seems it is fixed at Chrome 62.

I have a RewriteRule like below

```
RewriteRule ^/ShowGuide/?$ https://<website>/help.pdf [L,NC,R,QSA]
```

With Chrome 61, the PDF was not opening, in console it was showing the message

```
"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "
```

We tried to add mime type in the rewrite rule as below but it didn't help.

```
RewriteRule ^/ShowGuide/?$ https://<website>/help.pdf [L,NC,R,QSA, t:application/pdf]
```

I have updated my Chrome to latest 62 version and it started to showing the PDF again. But the message is still there in the console.

With all other browsers, it was/is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

I had similar problem.
Got message in js

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv

But I also got message in chrome console

> Mixed Content: The site at 'https://my-site/' was loaded
> over a secure connection, but the file at
> 'https://my-site/Download?id=99a50c7b'
> was redirected through an insecure connection.  This file should be
> served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked

It says here that you need to use an secure connection (but scheme is **https** in message already, strangely...).

The problem is that href for file downloading builded on server side. And this href used **http** in my case.

### The solution

So I changed scheme to **https** when build href for file downloading.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of csv file downloads (lots of tests) chrome asked whether to allow more downloads from this page. I just dismissed the window. After that chrome did not download the file any more but the console sayed:

"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv"

I could solve that issue by restarting chrome (completely Ctrl-Shift-Q).

[Update] Not sure why this post was deleted but it provided the solution for me. I had gotten the message earlier about trying to download multiple files and must have answered no. I got the "Resource interpreted..." message until I restarted the browser; then it worked perfectly. For some cases, this may be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file name was too long, and got the same error. Once shortened below 200 chars worked fine. (limit might be 250?)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was serving from my file system. Once I started with a http server chrome could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same trouble with a download manager I created. The problem I was having involved the file name being too long and the extension being clipped off.

Example: 
File Name : Organizational Protocols and Other Things That are Important.pd

```
<?php
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$File_Name");
?>
```

Solution: Increased the MySQL database field to 255 to store the file name, and performed a length check before saving the blob. If the length > 255 trim it down to 250 and add the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and I hope this will work for you.

```
var Interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (ReportViewer) {
                    ReportViewer.prototype.PrintReport = function () {
                        switch (this.defaultPrintFormat) {
                            case "Default":
                                this.DefaultPrint();
                                break;
                            case "PDF":
                                this.PrintAs("PDF");
                                previewFrame = document.getElementById(this.previewFrameID);
                                previewFrame.onload = function () { previewFrame.contentDocument.execCommand("print", true, null); }
                                break;
                        }
                    };
                    clearInterval(Interval);
                }
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this today, and my issue was that my `Content-Disposition` tag was wrongly set.
It looks like for both `pdf` & `application/x-zip-compressed`, you're supposed to set it to `inline` instead of `attachment`.

So to set your header, Java code would look like this:

```
...
String fileName = "myFileName.zip";
String contentDisposition = "attachment";
if ("application/pdf".equals(contentType)
    || "application/x-zip-compressed".equals(contentType)) {
    contentDisposition = "inline";
}
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition + "; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

I literally quote Saeed Neamati (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587434/760777):

> In your request header, you have sent Content-Type: text/html which means that you'd like to interpret the response as HTML. Now if even server send you PDF files, your browser tries to understand it as HTML.

**The solution**

Send the bloody correct header. Send the correct mime type of the file. Period!

**How?**

Aaah. That totally depends on what you are doing (OS, language).

My problem was with a dynamically created download link in javascript. The link is for downloading an mp3 file.
An mp3 file is not a document, neither is a pdf, a zip file, a flac file and the list goes on.

So I created the link like this:

```html
<form method="get" action="test.mp3"> 
  <a href="#" onclick="this.closest(form).submit();return false;" target="_blank">
    <span class="material-icons">
      download
    </span>
  </a>
</form>
```

and I changed it to this:

```html
<form method="get" action="test.mp3" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <a href="#" onclick="this.closest(form).submit();return false;" target="_blank">
    <span class="material-icons">
      download
    </span>
  </a>
</form>
```

Problem solved. Adding an extra attribute to the form tag solved it. But there is no generic solution. There are many different scenario's.
When you send a file from the server (you created it dynamically with a language like CX#, Java, PHP), you have to send the correct header(s) with it.

Side note: And be careful not to send anything (text!) before you send your header(s).

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error, the solution was to put the attribute

```
target = "_ blank"
```

Finally :

```
<a href="/uploads/file.*" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Where `*` is the extension of your file to download.

Comment: this is not a solution. It just opens a new tab and download the file in that tab. Any error / warning occurred also would have been reported in that tab's debug console and not in the present tab's debug console. Now, you just don't see the problem. But, actually it is not fixed.