# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip (chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a php script that copy a zip file on the server and then create an html link to that zip file.

The link looks like this:

```
<a href="mydir/myzipfile.zip">Link</a>
```

The problem I have is that when I click on the link when using Chrome, I get this warning message in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip
```

The link doesn't event point to some php header functions, it just a standard href link, yet I have this warning message. Do you have any idea why?
thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip ; in general, you are trying to **open** a ZIP-file in your browser (rather than **save** it to a disk).

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov what is the difference? window.location = url_to_zip, what other way is there to do this?

Comment: @Johannes, you might want to check out Tip#1 from http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/03/24/four-tips-for-setting-up-http-file-downloads/

Comment: I also get `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/x-msvideo:` when clicking in the video thumbs in this page: http://luis.impa.br/photo/00_filmes.html Chrome tries to save the video instead of playing it. Any clues how to solve this in `html4`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)