# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, mime-types, asp.net-web-api

I'm unable to successfully download a file from the server using a Web API get call. The download seems to start but then Chrome throws:

**"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip"**

Firefox doesn't say that but the download still fails.

What am I doing wrong in the following setup?:

```
    [HttpGet, Route("api/extractor/downloadresults")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadResultFiles()
    {
        int contentLength = 0;
        this.ResultFiles.ForEach(f => contentLength = contentLength + f.FileSize);

        var streamContent = new PushStreamContent((outputStream, httpContext, transportContent) =>
        {
           ...zip files...
        });

        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        streamContent.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
        streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "result.zip"
        };

        var response = Request.CreateResponse();

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Content = streamContent;
    }
```

I trigger the download via:

```
  window.location.href = "api/extractor/downloadresults";
```

With the resulting headers:

**Request Headers**

```
  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Connection:keep-alive
  Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=ibwezezeutmu2gpajfnpf41p
  Host:localhost:47384
  Referer:http://localhost:47384/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=result.zip
  Content-Length:436102
  Content-Type:application/zip
  Date:Mon, 16 Dec 2013 22:36:31 GMT
  Expires:-1
  Persistent-Auth:true
  Pragma:no-cache
  Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
  X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcbmV3VG9vbGJveFxUb29sYm94XFRvb2xib3guV2ViXGFwaVx0ZXJtZXh0cmFjdG9yXGRvd25sb2FkcmVzdWx0ZmlsZXM=?=
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I have the same problem. What is the solution to fix this warning? Thanks

Comment: @VAAA I never found a solution, please post if you did. I ended up going with a non-streaming solution, but it is far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the request headers, for example the accept header?

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip) you can find a similar question, some of the solutions suggested there may help you.