# Download external zip file from angular triggered on a button action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an angular app and I allow users to download zip files by clicking on a button that calls on a controller method via `ng-click`.

Inside the angular method, I'm calling `window.open(url, '_self', false)` (the same applies for `window.location.assign(url)`)

The zip download is working fine, however I'm seeing this warning in Chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/octet-stream

I'm stuck to using a button as from what I've seen `<a href="url" download>` will do the job.

Any ideas on how this can be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Add the correct headers on your server ;-)

Comment: headers look ok to me: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: filename=grammars-20140317-144045.zip
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 17 Mar 2014 17:14:57 GMT`

Comment: it's rather the request that's missing something?

Comment: I don't think so. Please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6587393/617996).

Comment: I've seen this one, definitely the same problem, Chrome issue

Answer (score 1):

Please try it like this:

```
window.open(url, '_blank')
```