# Chrome says: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Tags: google-chrome, download, mime-types, docx

I am offering a file for download from my site, which is working. However, I am noticing this behavior from Chrome.

I think I have the correct MIME Type set but Chrome is showing this message and also marks the request in red.

The MIME type I have set is:

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Is this the expected behavior for `*.docx` files? It seems like I may be doing something wrong.

[image]

Comment: Is this a dynamic download or a static one? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip) you can add the "download" attribute to the <a> tag. I'm seeing the same thing with application/pdf but (a) the PDF renders/downloads fine, and (b) it's dynamically generated so I have no <a> tag.

Comment: This is a dynamic download.

Answer (score 24):

Don't worry about the Chrome warning.
You are using a valid MIME Type for .docx files.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9891) in the Chrome bug tracker, a commenter on January 29, 2014 states that this may be caused by a missing Content-Length header. It doesn't fix the problem for me, however, where I return a dynamically generated PDF based on a form POST.

If nothing else, maybe add to or star the issue there. It may be innocuous.

Comment: if the server is using HTTP/1.1 Chunked response it shouldn't be setting Content-Length anyway. So Chrome is a bit broken if it cannot stream an octet-stream properly that way...

Answer (score 8):

The MIME type for your file is correct and actually does not matter here.

If your file is put inside an `<a>` element (whether it's static or dynamic), you need to add the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) to squeeze the warning.

Something similar happens to Edge as well, and adding `download` attribute solves it as well.

[image: Edge: Navigation occurred. DOCTYPE expected.]

Comment: It did not follow the link and issued a warning on localhost on my PC when I switched to Chrome's mobile mode in browser. But when I launched it locally on my mobile and tapped the link which leads to my CV, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Chrome seemingly does not suppress the warning if the resource to download does not have the same _origin_. Is this an expected behavior specified in the spec? -- Oh yea, thinking about it, it’s an obvious security feature: that way nobody can download resources you don't own as types you want it to be.