# why am I receiving this error when trying to display a PDF?

Tags: c#

"**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf**"

This is only happening on Chrome. Note: I am using ITextSharp.PDF. 
any ideas?

Here is my header:

```
 private void ShowPdf(string pdf_location, string community_name, DateTime date_issued, string type, string community_city, string community_state)
        {
            //Get base certificate pdf, add school name and date, and open the pdf on the user's computer
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader
            ("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=certificate.pdf");

            if (type == "certified")
            {
                Response.BinaryWrite(CommunityWildlifeHabitat.Models.PDF_DesignerCertifed.ReturnPDFByteStream(pdf_location, community_name, date_issued));
            } 
            if (type == "registered")
            {
                Response.BinaryWrite(CommunityWildlifeHabitat.Models.PDF_DesignerRegistered.ReturnPDFByteStream(pdf_location, community_name, date_issued, community_city, community_state));
            }
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: check this link,hope this will be helped to you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at that post ... tried a bunch of stuff but nothing is working. It seems like this is a common issue.

Comment: also, this is not happening locally ... this is happening when deploying to Q&A server

Comment: most one said ignore that chrome error :P