# Correct headers, but Chrome says "Resource interpreted as Document"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express, node-archiver

I read a lot of questions like this one, but I really can't figure it out...

I use the [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) Node.js modules. I want to simply send a zip file to the client. My code looks roughly like this:

```
res.set("Content-Type", "application/zip");
archive = archiver("zip", {store: true});
archive.pipe(res);
```

When requested, the zip file is transferred correctly, but Chrome complains:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip

If I do something stupid like setting the content type to `text/json`, I get:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/json

So apparently what I'm setting in Node.js is doing its job and something else is the problem. It says the resource was *transferred with MIME type applicatioin/zip*, but **interpreted** as Document.

**How do I make it not interpret as Document?**

---

Also, I tried these ways of setting the content type:

```
res.type("application/zip");
res.contentType("application/zip");
```

But I got the same result.

Mozilla, on the other hand, doesn't complain about anything. Some answers to similar questions said this warning can be ignored. Should I ignore it too? Could the problem be that the archive is piping directly to the response object? Although (I repeat), the zip is sent *successfully*.

### Edit:

Setting `Content-Disposition` doesn't work too:

```
res.set({
    "Content-Type": "application/zip",
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename='images.zip'"
});
```

I also use an `<iframe>` to initiate the request:

```
document.getElementById("iframe-downloader").src = requestUrl;
```

The reason is because I don't want page redirects. The only way I could manage to do it was this way.

### Edit:

Changing my Chrome settings how [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302014/3130281) points out doesn't work as well.

### Edit:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24118318/3130281) says it's because of the `<iframe>`. If I make the request through a simple `<form>` with `action="/archive"`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: This possible duplicate contains several different answers of which one could fit. Have a look at ► [**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip)

Comment: Well, setting the `.src` on an iframe tells the browser to EXPECT a web page, but you aren't sending a web page - thus the warning.  That's the source of your issue.   Please explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish in your web page?  Are you just trying to trigger a file download based on a button push?

Comment: I'm trying to download a generated file from the server without page redirects. Also, I don't think the iframe is the problem. As I said in my edits, if I use a simple form with `action` attribute, I still get the warning.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov in general, `location.href = '/path/to/download.zip'` can be used to trigger a download without redirecting, provided that the server sets a `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 2):

I think that means Chrome is trying to display the file as a webpage, which is not what you wanted.

Add the header: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.ext"`

Comment: Nope... still does it. Although I was looking for a way to rename the downloaded file and I can - with this header. Thanks a lot! I still get this damn warning, though.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov take a look at [`res.download()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download) as well for setting the download's filename

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem; I had a formular based post request which resulted in a file. Having the MIME Type and Content-Disposition set generated that very warning. 
I somewhere read, that new files should be openend in a new tab and the warning vanished.
(But also could be because the new page was open and closing in no time ... so I couldn't verify if that warning appeared there)

Best,
Jan