# binary pdf browser error: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: node.js, express, pdf-generation

Despite setting the correct MIME type, I get a warning in Chrome v79 saying:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf

Trying to serve a pdf generated using pdfmake with a binary output.  I set the MIME header correctly, but still Chrome gives this error.

```
createPdf = async () => {
    const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
    const Promise = require("bluebird");
    var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{ try {
        var chunks = [];
        pdfDoc.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
        pdfDoc.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
        pdfDoc.end();
    } catch(err) {
        reject(err);
    }});
};

router.get('/get-pdf/:filename', async (req, res)=>{ 
    var binaryResult = await createPdf();
    res.contentType('application/pdf').send(binaryResult);
});
```

And the browser where the pdf is displayed inline:

```
<object data="/get-pdf/filename.pdf" type="application/pdf" 
        width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

**Note**:  Setting the `Content-Disposition` at the server does not affect the error or cause the error to go away.

Comment: are you able to set the content-disposition at the same time you set the mime type?  eg Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf

Comment: @PaulJowett Yes, but setting the Content-Disposition does not resolve the error.

Comment: That's a shame.  Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: There is a similar StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-zip), but none of the answers solve my problem specifically (and the question is different).