# Express App Post Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am having an odd issue making a POST request to my express app.

I have tested the API using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) however when I copy the request code from Postman either the AJAX or XHR the request fails and the express app returns an undefined express body.

The console on the site spits out the following:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json
```

The request looks like this (AJAX):

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://thedomainhere.com/hello",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "0158785a-7ff5-f6a3-54ba-8dfc152976fc"
  },
  "data": {
    "senderEmail": "hello@hello.com"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Why would this work on Postman and in the console using Curl, but not from a web document?

Comment: I also have Cors enabled so shouldn't be an issue there.

Comment: As this answer suggests, set the response type to text/html: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7053252/1373554

Comment: How would you do that in the express app @gjegadesh?

Comment: your content-type value doesn't match your data. crossdomain is almost never needed. async's default value is true. stop just throwing spaghetti at the wall.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery first makes OPTIONS request without POST payload, when you try to make cross-origin ajax, and expects the following headers to be sent in response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

To set headers on response in Express you can do the following middleware somewhere in the beginning (also see NodeJS [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) for `setHeader`):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    if(req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Also [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) post about enabling CORS on express may be useful.

To understand why OPTIONS is sent in this case, you can read an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12320467/1580941) question.

That's the first possible reason, why you get empty body.

Also try to change `content-type` to `contentType` (as in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) and pass a string in the data

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    "senderEmail": "hello@hello.com"
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Vadim - how do I set that response header in the express app?

Comment: Still getting "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json" @Vadim - Thanks for your edit though

Answer (score 0):

You should set the response type to text/html like this, for example:

```
app.post("/route", function(req, res) {
    ...
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html'); // or 'text/plain', etc.
    ...
    res.send();
});
```