# flask-restful needs jsonify else it doesn't work

Tags: python, json, rest, api

I am making an API with Flask and Flask-RESTful. When I went to a url in my browser to make a HTTP GET request I got a strange warning in the chromium developer console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:8080/api/articles".
```

So I looked it up and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-json) article suggested that I changed the mime type to `text/html` which didn't work.

Also when I tested this out with my front-end angular didn't automatically  turn it into json, what it normally does.

So why does this happen?
I noticed one strange thing. A normal view with `jsonify` that returned the same thing as the flask restfull resource did work. So I thought I try to do add the `jsonify` to the return and it works.

My question is why does this only work when I use the `jsonify` function and otherwise not. In the docs of `Flask-RESTful` it says it doesn't need the `jsonify` function. Because the `@api.representation('application/json')` uses `json.dumps` and adds mime type on every outgoing response.

```
class ArticleList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        results = models.Article.query.all()
        return [x.as_dict() for x in results]  # doesn't work
        # return jsonify([x.as_dict() for x in results]) this does work
```

I also did GET request with curl with the `jsonify` and without.

**With jsonify**

```
panter@panter:~$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/articles -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/articles HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 560
< Date: Sat, 15 Apr 2017 19:46:46 GMT
< 
[
  {
    "body": "boeeeeeem", 
    "id": 1, 
    "picture": null, 
    "timestamp": "za, 15 apr 2017 17:56:48", 
    "title": "Vandaag in nuenen een grote explosie!"
  }
]
```

**without jsonify**

```
panter@panter:~$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/articles -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/articles HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 466
< Date: Sat, 15 Apr 2017 19:43:20 GMT
< 
[{"body": "boeeeeeem", "picture": null, "id": 1, "timestamp": "za, 15 apr 2017 17:56:48", "title": "Vandaag in nuenen een grote explosie!"}]
```

Also note that I have changed `@api.representation('application/json')` to add some custom headers:

```
@api.representation('application/json')
def output_json(data, code, headers=None):
    resp = make_response(json.dumps(data), code)
    all_headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }.copy()
    all_headers.update(headers)
    resp.headers.extend(all_headers)

    return resp
```

When using jsonify, these custom headers aren't used.