# Is there an issue retriving json data when using vue, axios, and laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to replicate a tutorial on vuecasts (https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/18).

Everything looks fine and I don't get any errors except a warning:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/json: "http://vueme.app:8000/skills"

I already tried to change content-type to text/html as suggested here:
[Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json warning in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-json)

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('skills', function(){
return ['javascript', 'php', 'python'];
});
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="root">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="skill in skills" v-text="skill"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script scr="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script scr="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script scr="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data:{
        skills:[]
    },
    mounted(){
        axios.get('/skills').then(response => this.skills = response.data);
    }
});
```

What's not working?

Comment: try `return response()->json(['javascript', 'php', 'python']);` into your `web.php`

Comment: @Treast nope, same thing. Mind you, I get that warning on the 'skills' page and not on the main page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json warning in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934393/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-json)

Comment: @DanielBeck Already tried that before asking the question. Doesn't work.