# js warning: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: javascript, jquery, warnings, jsonp, cloudant

i´m firing an ajax/jsonp request to my cloudant app:

```
    var obj = $.ajax({
        url: "http://xyz",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {  
            //SOME CODE  
        },
        error: function() {
            //SOME CODE
        }
    });
```

the response is ok and i can read out my data. 
but I´m getting the following js warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
```

i need to make this request an jsonp request (cross domain policy), AFAIK jsonp returns as a script and gets executed by the
browser. 
do i have to set a request header? 
I tried it with the 'accepts' and 'converters' options, but didn't make it work yet.
(I´m using GoogleChrome, but also happens in Safari/FF)

cheers, 
tom

PS: I want to get rid of the warning as this ajax request gets triggered every 2 seconds. So the console looks pretty bad...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: **[Chrome says “Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.”, what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)**

Answer (score 4):

The server should send a `Content-Type` header set to `text/javascript` when it sends the JSONP script.

Comment: Thanks. But it is on cloudant, which always sends "text/plain". I wasn't able change the Content-Type. Is it also possible to accept different Content-Types on the client? Or does anyone know if it is possible to change it on cloudant?

Comment: You'd be doing a lot of people a favor if you reported this as a bug to the cloudant developers.  This is probably a case where you're best served waiting for a fix from them.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB itself is sending the text/plain content-type. The only other type you can convince it to send is 'application/json' if you send 'Accept: application/json' as a header.

It seems that CouchDB should send text/javascript if delivering a jsonp response, though. If you could file a ticket I'm sure it would get done.

Comment: this was raised as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1274 since it's an issue in core CouchDB. Probably resolve it in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on target server, because it's setting `Content-Type: Text/plain`

You can't enforce it without access to target server. It should be `Content-Type: text/javascript`

Comment: Do you know if that's possible in cloudant?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending any encoding information in the headers? I had a problem with CouchDB responses and discovered that adding `charset=utf-8` to my `Accept` or `Content-Type` heading resulted in CouchDB returning the `text/plain` content instead of the `application/json` I was expecting. Perhaps you can solve this by altering your header if the case is similar enough.