# What is the right extension for files with JSONP?

Tags: file, text, jsonp, plaintext

I have a file with [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (hard-written callback) and I named it `file.jsonp`. Unfortunately server treats it as "text/plain" and browser returns warning:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.

Calling it `file.json` causes the same warning. So what is the right extension? It works with `file.js`, but I don't think it is the right way.

Comment: This means your server doesn't know the content type to specify when it hands out file.jsonp. How and where you specify MIME types varies by web server, but see this question for the answer if you're using Apache (and good info all around): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Comment: I know, but I'm curious why it doesn't:). I don't know what is a standard naming for jsonp files.

Answer (score 4):

JSONP is nothing but pure javascript code. So the right extension for it is `.js`. And the correct mime type is `application/javascript`.