# Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am receiving the error: "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined." inside developer tools when I load my page. I'm not sure why it's doing this or how to solve it.

Wondering if anyone has any insight on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Google fonts, it could happen too.

It should be a problem of Web Inspector does not recognize `application/x-font-woff` as a valid mime-type.

Comment: I wish, given that its *Google* Chrome, and *Google* Webfonts, that they would do something to hide this warning. With up to 3 or 4 google fonts per project sometimes, it pollutes the console quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with empty image requests, e.g.

```
<img src="" />
```

or in an external/inline stylesheet

```
background:url();
```

They generate an additional request for the current url (or css file) with the wrong mime type(image).

As I found out, the latter one disables the live-css-editing features of the chrome dev tools.

Comment: I was upgrading an old site, nesting folders and calling the root stylesheet. It had image background set thus: `background-image:url(../images/background-image.jpg)`. Removing the `..` resolved my resource interpretation issue..

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I saw the same thing. Apparently this is a server-side issue.

[Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)

Answer (score 0):

As others already said this can be caused by a few different things, but it never really matters, as long as your content is displayed fine. If not, it is probably a mime-type problem on the server side, which could be solved by adding a rule to the .htaccess file in Apache.