# jquery.js call from HTML syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page generated by an objective-C application and I want to load and open it in a local directory (not in a web server). The javascripts jquery.js and jquery.plot.js are stored in the same directory before the page is loaded.
I made the HTML page by following closely the examples available on http://flot.googlecode.com/
The scripts are declared in the HTML page as follows :

```
<script src="jquery.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.flot.pack.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I open the page, the expected graph (generated by the scripts) doesn't show up and I have the following syntax error in the javascript console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

The script source in the javascript console is made of strange (chinese ?) ideograms which are obviously "unexpected token" if it is what the browser sees.
I have the same problem with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. 
The problem is not systematic because sometimes, it works !. 
I have made tests with files prepared manually and again it works sometimes only. 
I have also copied the same file which didn't work in another directory where the jquery scripts were present and, surprise, it worked ! but not always...
I have exhausted all my ideas on this problem and your help will be very much appreciated

Comment: You need to wrap any code in your post or else it won't show correctly.

Comment: This is your sixth question, you really should be marking things up correctly by now. When you were typing your question, to the right there was a **How to Format** box. Well worth a read, as are the various bits of information available via the **[?]** button above the text area. There's also a preview area underneath so you can see how your question will look when it's posted, and of course an "edit" link once you post the question if, on re-reading it (and you did bother, right?) you see that some of the formatting didn't work. Bothering with all this shows respect for other people's time.

Comment: Did you propose this edit to add new information? If you log in your can just edit your question which makes much more sense.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Salem, try using `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.7/jquery.flot.min.js` as your `src=` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the JavaScript from an external source?  I know I have had problems when copying from JSFiddle for example.  Try removing any whitespace and see if that will get rid of the illegal token error.

Comment: The zipped flot library comes from http://code.google.com/p/flot/downloads. I do not see any whitespaces I could remove

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and it was because the server on which my javascript was being hosted wasn't configured to send the javascript file with the correct MIME type.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text).

Instead of fixing my server, I just opted to use a CDN path from [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/):

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.7/jquery.flot.min.js
```