# Auto refresh a specific div blogger javascript

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, reload, blogger

I use a Javascript widget on a blogspot. It include a div with some javascripts that get some "non-statical" strings from a server and print them on the page. Until here everything works fine, the problem is that I would like to update the execution of this div every few seconds in order to have updated strings, without refreshing the whole page, but just the specific widget (div). I have added another script that tries to refresh the specific div, but I had no luck. Please see the code below

```
<div id="info">
<b>Song:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
<br />
<b>Listeners:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
<br />
<b>Server Status:</b> 
<img src="xxxxx.gif" alt="Stream status" width="17" height="17" align="absmiddle" />
</div>
```

Script for refreshing:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = startInterval;
    function startInterval()
    {
        setInterval("startTime();",5000);
    }

    function startTime()
    {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = ??? // reload div    
    }
  </script>
```

Additionally something like this could be used, but this method reload the whole page and not the specific div.

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    parent.location.reload(true);
}, 5000); 
</script>
```

Comment: `startTime()` is executing, but `document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML` this doesn't have any effect. Try adding a `console.log("startTime()");` in startTime and see if it is running or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, yes the function startTime() is executed correctly, I have tried by replacing the code with something else and it works fine. The problem is obviously with the document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML; code which is wrong.

Comment: You need code to get the text from the server, then. Look into jQuery and $.get().

Comment: Sorry for not making my question clear. I get the text from the server and it appears on the screen correctly. My problem is that I would like to update this operation every 5 sec.

Comment: "get the text from the server" with javascript?

Comment: Yes Tasos, it is not exactly a server, a webpage that just returns a script. But this is not my problem. The problem is how to auto refresh the widget every 5 sec.

Comment: can you post the full code? you essentially want to call whatever function the widget contains in your setInterval.

Comment: Look on the answer...

Comment: I have posted the full code. Actually the widget ends where the </div> is. The other is extra code.

Comment: the specific id is one and the script is interest is info?

Comment: That's correct Mirko, The div (which is included in the widget) works just fine, but it is not updated over time. That's why I tried adding the code bellow the div.

Answer (score 5):

***Last Update***

I try with Ajax and with created element.
With this technique, load the contains of the scripts but the `document.write()` not function.
Because this `write()` need the `refresh page()!!`

Just returning a value from a function does not place that value into an HTML element in any way. One could either use `document.write` (not recommended), or access the element via its id and write the desired element content via `.innerHTML=…`

Explain.

If you will be displaying it on page, first create an element with an id "message" (you can write anything you want, but remember, id's have to be unique on the page) like

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

and then use

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "New title";
```

or if you are using jQuery:

```
$("#message").html("New title");
```

or if you are using a console enabled browser (Firefox, Chrome etc.)

```
console.log("New title");
```

instead of

```
document.write("New title");
```

**THEN** **`document.write` only for page loading time.**

You have to change the scripts and replace `document.write()`

I put the my code with `createElement` and on the comment you look the my work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
<div id="info">
<b>Song:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk23-free:5106">You appear to have javascript turned off.</script>
<br />
<b>Listeners:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/listeners/uk23-free:5106">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
<br />
<b>Server Status:</b> 
<img src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/status/uk23-free:5106.gif" alt="Stream status" width="17" height="17" align="absmiddle" />
</div>


      <script type="text/javascript">
      function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {

var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},timeoutPeriod);

function myTimer()
{

          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="";
          var b=document.createElement('B');
          b.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Song") );
          document.getElementById("info").appendChild(b);
// span.innerHTML="";
// span.appendChild( document.createTextNode("hello") );
// document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = 'newtext';



           var src1 = 'http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk23-free:5106',
                script1 = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
                script1.type="text/javascript";
           script1.src = src1;
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(script1);

           var br= document.createElement('BR');
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(br);
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(br);
           var b=document.createElement('B');
           b.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Listeners") );
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(b);
           var src2 = 'http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/listeners/uk23-free:5106',
                script2 = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
                script2.type="text/javascript";
           script2.src = src2;
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(script2);

           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(br);

           var b=document.createElement('B');
           b.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Server Status") );
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(b);

              var src3 = 'http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk23-free:5106',
                script3 = document.createElement('IMG');

           script3.src = src3;
           script3.alt="Stream status";
           script3.width="17";
           script3.height="17";
           script3.align="absmiddle";
           document.getElementById("info").appendChild(script3);
//              
//              document.body.appendChild(script);
//              
//              document.body.info.appendChild(b);
//            document.getElementsByTagName('b')[1].appendChild( document.createTextNode("Listeners") );
//             document.body.info.appendChild(script2);
//            var br= document.createElement('BR');
//            
//            document.body.info.appendChild(br);
}   
//    // create an object of the head element of current page
//   var hdEl = document.getElementsByTagName("song");
// 
//   //check for previously appended child 
//   //(it ensures that each time the button is pressed it
//   // removes the previously loaded script element)
//   if (hdEl.childNodes.length > 1) {
//    hdEl.removeChild(hdEl.lastChild);
//   }
// 
//   // Now add this new element to the head tag
//   
//   
//     //Create a 'script' element  
//   var scrptE = document.createElement("script");
// 
//   // Set it's 'type' attribute   
//   scrptE.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
// 
//   // Set it's 'language' attribute
//   scrptE.setAttribute("language", "JavaScript");
// 
//   // Set it's 'src' attribute
//   scrptE.setAttribute("src", "http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk23-free:5106");
// 
//   // Now add this new element to the head tag
//   hdEl.appendChild(scrptE);
// //   document.getElementsByTagName("song").appendChild(scrptE);
//     //This is a old:
//    setTimeout("alert("ojk");",timeoutPeriod);
//     //  This function!!!
//  setTimeout("document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML;",timeoutPeriod);
// var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
// var oScript= document.createElement("script");
// oScript.type = "text/javascript";
// oScript.src="other.js";
// oHead.appendChild( oScript);

}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

**THEN....**

I change your site and now function!!!
And on the my pc this site is refresh every 5 second!!!
You have always the two particular errors.

This work for you but you have the particular error.
`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://xxxx"`.  on the sentence n° 13 and also for sentence n°18.

```
http://xxxx
```

This error I find with the tool's chrome (Inspect element).

The solution is on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003107/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-plain-for-l) or prefier the [blog](http://joshua.doodnauth.com/blog/2013/02/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-textplain/).

I have the software is Kubuntu (KDE + Ubuntu) and I don't know for change the value 's registry.

**Solution:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
<div id="info">
<b>Song:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">You appear to have javascript turned off.</script>
<br />
<b>Listeners:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
<br />
<b>Server Status:</b> 
<img src="xxxx.gif" alt="Stream status" width="17" height="17" align="absmiddle" />
</div>


      <script type="text/javascript">
   function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    //This is a old:
    //setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
    //  This function!!!
setTimeout("document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML;",timeoutPeriod);
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or other solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
</head>
<body >
<div id="info">
<b>Song:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">You appear to have javascript turned off.</script>
<br />
<b>Listeners:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxxx">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
<br />
<b>Server Status:</b> 
<img src="xxxxx.gif" alt="Stream status" width="17" height="17" align="absmiddle" />
</div>


      <script type="text/javascript">
//    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
//  setTimeout("document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML;",timeoutPeriod);
//         document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=document.getElementById("info").innerHTML
// }

            window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 5000);  
            function refreshDiv(){   
                document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;  
            }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a old site but not refresh the site.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="info">
<b>Song:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">You appear to have javascript turned off.</script>
<br />
<b>Listeners:</b>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">
You appear to have javascript turned off.
</script>
<br />
<b>Server Status:</b> 
<img src="xxxx.gif" alt="Stream status" width="17" height="17" align="absmiddle" />
</div>


      <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML; 
}, 5000);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just searching for a way to reload just a piece of code, rather than reloading the whole page. Additionally, this is a blogspot JS widget, I have a lot of restrictions using other stuff than JS

Comment: Song: Unknown - 70 s 8o s 90 s MEGAMIX Classic Project 1 by Nicolas Escobar 
Listeners: 0 
Server Status: <img>

This, print on the site every 5 second, always (on the my pc)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this is not working. <head> is not allowed into a blogger Javascript widget, I have tried to add the code into template's <head> but no luck. I would like to inform that I do not have access to the server giving the info. You said you have always the same string on your pc, that's the problem, the server change the string after some times, if you press refresh now, there would be different strings. That's my point to "auto-refresh" this specific widget.

Comment: NOw I understand the your case and your working with some radio?

Comment: Yes, that's correct Mirko. I host the radio page on blogspot and gathering info from the shoutcast server regarding song title, listener etc... However blogspot, has too many restrictions regarding implementing code for widgets. I do not want to refresh the whole page, cause the radio streaming will be refreshed too, so the listener will hear gaps every 5 sec.

Comment: <head> or <body> elements are to allowed to be included into the widget.

Comment: Try with:  function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
 setTimeout("document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML;",timeoutPeriod);}

Comment: When this song Unknown - Greek Rock Vol 1 by Petrosk finish?

Comment: Right now, I just skip it, cause it is 60min remix

Comment: I wait for the finish Steppenwolf - Born To Be Wild..
I change script

Comment: I suggest for you of use the page in php because you can refresh only one page inside the site.

Comment: Where in this site because I haven't account?

Comment: This is the server status page, no need to have any account. Posted here just to observe the song title and listeners in real time

Comment: sorry for the delay,
I worked for an hour every day and I have also the my work.
You can use the document.write and you have to change the script.
I hope that I get a good reputation from you.

Answer (score 2):

here is a fiddle working example of how i typically declare my set interval functions...

this one is setting the inner html of my #info div to a timestamp just so u can see that it is  functional.

[fiddle here with set interval](http://jsfiddle.net/QZjV5/1/)
but i think there is another flaw in this process...

it looks like here you are updating the contents of the div to exactly the same html as they were before:

```
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').innerHTML;
```

this is likely your issue, the external scripts you are using are likely writing html, and you are just copying it rather than running those scripts again.   what you want to do is run some sort of AJAX call to rerun those scripts.

you can do this more easily with the jquery library if you are interested in going that route.  or to maintain strict javascript i would reccomend starting here:

[w3 ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: This is a blogspot JS widget, I have a lot of restrictions using other stuff than JS

Comment: i would start with that w3 ajax tutorial then, strictly javascript as i mentioned no additional libraries

Comment: Thank you for your help but the point is not to learn some Javascript commands or syntax (besides I was aware that the above  line of code is wrong, that's why I post it, in order to express the  subject of research). The  the point is to determine if there is the ability of reloading a specific piece of code via Javascript on a blogspot widget (or at least the whole widget) every few seconds.