# How to refresh div in javascript, which has another script as body?

Tags: javascript, ads

I was using an advertising service (banner) which had a simple refresh timer in it. Where I could specify after what time the advert should be reloaded (or a new one should be served)

I've switched my banner provider and the new one does not have that built in option.

I've tried refreshing the div normally but that doesn't work since the content seems to remain the same.

Any ideas on a javascript code which can refresh a banner ad?

```
<script langauge="javascript">  
window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 60000);  
function refreshDiv(){  
    document.getElementById("advert_div").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

and here is the advertisers div

```
<div id="advert_div">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                LSM_Slot({
                    adkey: '645451',
                    ad_size: '300x250',
                    slot: 'slot656464'
                });
            //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try with setInterval function that call "refreshBanner" function?And are you sure that you banner doesn't change inly when a user click on? @FahimAkhter

Comment: Could you provide code you expected to work?

Comment: Forgot to add the code. Added now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say my idea or suggest.
I had one situation but there was the script with `document.write()` and this is not that you used.
Info: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630569/auto-refresh-a-specific-div-blogger-javascript/16630717#16630717) (I was writing before the update's question)

**[2. idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945789/using-settimeout-to-delay-timing-of-jquery-actions/16945847)**
In your case

```
  <script language="javascript">  
    window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 60000);  
    function refreshDiv(){  
        document.getElementById("advert_div").innerHTML;
    }
    </script>
```

The `document.getElementById("advert_div").innerHTML` miss `=` as what?

Example

```
document.getElementById("advert_div").innerHTML="<p>Welcome</p>"
```

**EDIT:**

You can create the element with

```
document.getElementById("advert_div").innerHTML="";
         var src1 = 'script',
                script1 = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
                script1.type="text/javascript";
           script1.src = src1;
           document.getElementById("advert_div").appendChild(script1);
```

This is a banal example but you can create the function in every banner and create the function:

```
"use strict";
var name = "foo";
var func = new Function(
     "return function " + name + "(){ alert('sweet!')}"
)();

//call it, to test it
func();
```

[Info:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905492/dynamic-function-name-in-javascript)

```
function refreshDiv(){  

            document.getElementById("advert_div").innerHTML="";
            //Calling the function using the if
        }
```

Now I do not know exactly what you want to do and I writing my ideas.
Good luck and if you seek help.

Comment: html of the div is made from another script as you can see and I need to refresh that script essentially. So there is no hardcoded html like .write() in your case.

Comment: I looked at your thing again I think both of us have the same issue :) . We want a script to refresh a div with a script.

Comment: I do not recommend for use ´document.write()´' and pleasing one up-vote.

Comment: And you can create element (script) putting the file external generated via script.
Explain in (edit) answer

Comment: I tried  innerHTML = innerHTML thing from your post seems to be working for me

Comment: Other idea I have added @FahimAkhter