# Using setTimeout to delay timing of jQuery actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to delay the swapping of text in a div. It should operate like a slider/carousel for text.

I must have the code wrong, as the final text replacement never happens.

Also, how would I animate introducing the replacement text (window blinds, for eg.)?

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#showDiv").click(function() {
        $('#theDiv').show(1000, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#theDiv').html('Here is some replacement text', function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#theDiv').html('More replacement text goes here');
                    }, 2500);
                });
            }, 2500);
        });
    }); //click function ends

}); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    Below me is a DIV called "theDiv".<br><br>
    <div id="theDiv" style="background-color:yellow;display:none;width:30%;margin:0 auto;">
        This text is inside the Div called "theDiv".
    </div><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="showDiv" value="Show DIV">



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The most appropriate tool for this would be `.queue()` I think...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`.html()` only takes a string OR a function as an argument, [not both](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). Try this:

```
 $("#showDiv").click(function () {
     $('#theDiv').show(1000, function () {
         setTimeout(function () {
             $('#theDiv').html(function () {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     $('#theDiv').html('Here is some replacement text');
                 }, 0);
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     $('#theDiv').html('More replacement text goes here');
                 }, 2500);
             });
         }, 2500);
     });
 }); //click function ends
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6evy9/)**

Comment: what if i put a <script></script> inside that div.. will the script will also be refreshed? or something.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
function explode(){
  alert("Boom!");
}
setTimeout(explode, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [jQuery's `delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) instead of `setTimeout()`.  It'll give you much more readable code.  Here's an example from the docs:

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

The only limitation (that I'm aware of) is that it doesn't give you a way to clear the timeout.  If you need to do that then you're better off sticking with all the nested callbacks that `setTimeout` thrusts upon you.

Comment: Actually, you can use `clearQueue()` to remove any animations that haven't been executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem
The menu closes a few seconds after mouse out (that if hover didn't fire),

```
//Set timer switch
$setM_swith=0;

$(function(){
    $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('dropdown'))
            $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
    $(".navbar-collapse").mouseleave(function(){
        $setM_swith=1;
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           if($setM_swith==1) {
             $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
             $setM_swith=0;} 
        }, 3000);
    });
    $(".navbar-collapse").mouseover(function() {
        $setM_swith=0;
    });
 });
```