# How can i create html automatic change page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example, I have pages page-A.html, page-B.html, page-C.html. When I click on the link in page-A, I want to move on to page-B and page-B will automatically move to page-C in 3 seconds without any action. So, how can i create this page-B ?

Comment: You're looking for the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Use SetTimeout Function. Link given below for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945789/using-settimeout-to-delay-timing-of-jquery-actions

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `setTimeout` method will execute code after a delay.  On Page B:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location='page-C.html';},2000);
```