# Chrome says “Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.”, without server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This problem even arises, when there is no server access whatsoever.
index.html is just accessing some locally stored JavaScript file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="timeline.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <p>The Body</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When displayed in the browser, Chrome says:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:  
file:///D:/Workspace/timeline/examples/engel-timeline/timelineReusable.v0.0/timeline.js".
```

How can I suppress this message? (Adding a 'content-type' doesn't help!)

Comment: I know it's not required in HTML5, but does adding `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script>` tag do anything? Also, and I know you said adding a `content-type` doesn't help, but I use this as my first line in the `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`. I wonder if that changes anything

Comment: Adding the suggested '<meta.../> line doesn't change anything. I tried this already after reading one of the other threads dealing with this problem, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/. This made me think that the problem doesn't depend on a server being available. (The answer is a setting in the Windows registry, see the second answer below.)

Comment: I was only suggesting things :) Didn't think they would fix, but just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 6):

I believe the reason for this is that your script is being loaded locally from your computer. It's directly accessing the file, so there are no request headers here, meaning there will be no MIME type that comes with your JS file.

If you upload your file on the Internet, then this will be fixed because it uses a different protocol (HTTP).

This problem should only end up happening when there is no server. If there is a server, then make sure you're using the server's URL, like `http://localhost:80/timeline.js`. And if that still is giving you a problem, then your server's MIME types need to be configured (though it's just a JavaScript file, so that shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: The message is just a nuisance. The script runs without problems. If I run it in Firefox, no message is shown! The following answer has the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try opening regedit: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js and either change or add string "Content Type" with value "text/javascript"

Comment: Thank you! This made the message disappear!

Comment: This is a great fix. A more detailed description is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12057490/1617395

Answer (score 0):

The error also arises in this situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/livehelp/livehelp_js.php>
```

indicating that Chrome is the problem, the code is good. Chrome is wrongly blocking a script sent in a php file. The script is not blocked in other browsers except IE 11 and only when Apache directive `Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"` is set.