# Blue Dot Menu displaying HTML as text

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

After the app menu html is retrieved, it is displayed as text instead of html. Chrome complains `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain`. I'm using MVC on the Force.com platform. I've tried specifying the content type of the response as "text/html" and "application/javascript", but neither worked.

**[EDIT 1]**

**Code**

```
<script>
   intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
      menuProxy: "https://c.na55.visual.force.com/"
     + "apex/bluedot",
      grantUrl: "https://c.na55.visual.force.com/"
     + "apex/authpage"
   });
</script>

<ipp:bluedot>
    <div id="intuitPlatformAppMenu">
        <a id="intuitPlatformAppMenuLogo" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Intuit App Center">
            <span id="intuitPlatformAppMenuDot">&nbsp;</span>
        </a>
        <div id="intuitPlatformAppMenuDropdown" style="display: none;">
            <div id="intuitPlatformAppMenuDropdownTop"></div>
            <div id="intuitPlatformAppMenuDropdownInner">
                <<=======
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ipp:bluedot>
```

*When dropdown is open, code is added at arrow location as string and a class 'open' is addedto #intuitPlatformAppMenuLogo.*

**Image**

[image: Blue dot menu code appears as string]

**[EDIT 2]**

**Server side apex code**

```
public with sharing class GetBlueDotMenu {
    public String response {get; set;}
    public GetBlueDotMenu() {
        QbApiController api = new QbApiController ('GET', 'QB API' , null, null, 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Account/AppMenu');
        response = api.execute();
    }
}
```

api.execute() returns the response body and saves it to `response` which is then rendered on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue arises from Visualforce's default rendering of strings as escaped. To fix it, the apex:outputText attribute `escaped` needs to be "false". See http://bit.ly/13CSXve

Answer (score 0):

PFB link - 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0060_auth_auth/widgets/blue_dot_menu

For IE8, you should add (as mentioned in the above doc)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="">
```

You can clear the browser's cache and try it again. 
Plz let me know how it goes.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same. Please see code and image above.

Comment: If possible, plz share the code behind 'https://c.na55.visual.force.com' [ ie menuProxy URL ]

Comment: Can you please test your code with just <ipp:blueDot></ipp:blueDot>? It should work. If it does not work then you can refer to other solutions in SO like this one for Force registry key entry similar to Visual Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003107/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-plain-for-l