# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

On all browsers: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:"file:///E:/Projetions%20Matcher/Canvas/jquery.min.js".

So jquery.min.js is loaded, but livello.js isn't. Why?

EDIT: I attempted to load it on a server but there was the same error

HTML:
....

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="livello.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

....

livello.js:

```
var c=document.getElementById("app"); 
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

function resize(){
c.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
c.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
var gameWidth = window.innerWidth;
var gameHeight = window.innerHeight;
var scaleToFitX = gameWidth / c.width;
var scaleToFitY = gameHeight / c.height;
var currentScreenRatio = gameWidth / gameHeight;
var optimalRatio = Math.min(scaleToFitX, scaleToFitY);
  c.style.width = c.width * optimalRatio + "px";
    c.style.height = c.height * optimalRatio + "px";
}
window.onresize=function(){resize();};

function clean()
{c.width=window.innerWidth;
c.height=window.innerHeight;}

clean();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text) or even better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003107/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-plain-for-l or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Resource+interpreted+as+Script+but+transferred+with+MIME+type+text%2Fplain

Comment: Also, you should really install a server instead of opening the files directly from the filesystem.

Comment: @Juhana: 1)no because I'm in file:/// and not in a server
2) But why jquery works also in local?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "Resource interpreted as script but..." is not an error but a notice. It won't cause the script to not work.

Comment: is exactly  that I want to know! Why livello.js doesn't work (but jquery.min.js works)?

Answer (score 1):

In your post you say 'On all browsers' but you only tagged Google Chrome so I will try to give a solution for both scenario's.

First of all the error doesn't say that jquery.min.js is loaded. It tells you that the `Content Type` is set to `text/plain` instead of `text/javascript`.

With this in mind the error can be on multiple places. Here are a few common places:

1) If you are calling jquery.min.js from a web page make sure that `<script type="text/javascript">`

2) It could be that something you have installed messed around with the `Content Type` in your registry. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003107/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-plain-for-l) for reference and method to fix it.

3) It could also be that the error is server side. Meaning the server side application sends the Javascript HTTP response header value as `text/plain` again instead of `text/javascript`. This **COULD** usually be the case when the Javascript is generated from a server side scripting language. But agian there could be a few other reasons for this happening.

4) It could also be that if you are running the script locally from your computer that no `Content Type` is received and that is defaulted to `text/plain` and hence the browser is unable to process it as Javascript.

I hope that one of these will help you solve your problem.

Comment: 0) I only tagged Chrome because there's a limit of 5 tags
1)jquery works
2)I use Linux Ubuntu, and jquery works
3)I'm using the page without any server
4)Why jquery works locally (jquery.min.js and livello.js are in the same folder)