# twitter bootstrap not linking to jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am going through Twitter Bootstrap tutorials and have been having problems with getting my initial output to work correctly. I've been researching the issue for a while, and it seems like the problem might be incorrect linking to `jquery`, but none of the posted code solutions have fixed my issue. The code below is from a tutorial and is not my own. In the tutorial, this code created a responsive collapsing `navbar`, however my output looks like this:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Twitter Bootstrap 3</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Fixed Navigation Bar with drop down menu
    =============================================-->

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> WORDS <a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials <b class="carrot"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Tutorials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: open your debugger tools and check whether any error occur

Comment: Are both the JavaScript files loading properly? And are you sure you're using the right versions of both jQuery and Bootstrap?

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy I think that the JavaScript files may not be loading properly, I'm not sure what I need to be doing differently. I downloaded jQuery version 1.11.1 uncompressed today, and bootstrap version 2.3.2 today

Comment: you need to point to the correct src, the name should be the same name as your file name

Comment: @Se0ng11 sorry for the delay, I had to look up how to check for errors. I have the following errors "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/Users/Adam/Documents/webpage_testing/js/jquery.js". attempt.htm:7
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/Users/Adam/Documents/webpage_testing/js/bootstrap.js". attempt.htm:8
"

Comment: @Se0ng11 the names are the are the same as the file names (I changed it to jquery.js as is seen in the code for consistancy with the tutorial code), sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: This might be an issue with your Windows registry. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003107/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-plain-for-l).

Comment: That link was relevent, and that issue was occuring. I made the fix that it described, and now there are no errors listed in the console. However, the output still looks the same

Comment: how bout go to the network tab in the debugger tools, refresh your page and see if there is any red color file appear in there?

Comment: @Se0ng11 There are no red color files, in fact based on this it looks like jquery is loading correctly http://imgur.com/DEYV5H7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for Bootstrap 3.x. In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195419/twitter-bootstrap-not-linking-to-jquery/25201393#comment39235927_25195419), you said you are using bootstrap 2.3.2 which is incompatible.

Linking the resources for Bootstrap 3 instead of those for version 2 will make your site work fine. See this bootplies as proof:

1. [with Bootstrap 3.2](http://www.bootply.com/Edvf3WRpzz)
2. [with Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://www.bootply.com/pdHNB0T9KW)

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, and I'm up and running now! Thank you for your help with the trouble shooting, it ended up being kind of a stupid error, but it was one that I would not have figured out on my own. Thank you also to Se0ng11 and NicolasMcCurdy to take time to help me out!