# error with ipinfodb

Tags: ajax, jquery, geolocation

i'm trying to use ipinfodb for marking the user position on gmap.
my jquery code is

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=<my api key>&ip=74.125.45.100",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    }

);
```

but i'm getting the following error on chrome

->Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=141cb28778f3fe2d8e55fdd8e4511ad1777…25.45.100&callback=jQuery1820355858133174479_1352640806111&_=1352640806113". 
->Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

what am i missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var YOUR_KEY = theKey;//"123"
    var theURL = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=" + YOUR_KEY + "&format=json&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theURL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'GET',

        success: function (data) {
            alert('worked');
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });//$.ajax({
```

Comment: welcome to stack-overflow :) you should consider putting in some text explaining why the above works.

Comment: The solution is to add dataType: "json" instead of dataType: "jsonp".