# Cannot pull a CSS file from web into my html page

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page reference a stylesheet on my github.

It is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic JavaScript Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/master/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Please be styled</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My expectation is that the `Please be styled` will be styled as per stylesheet. But it is not.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Open up your dev tools, go to the Network tab and check that your stylesheet is loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox logs an error in the console:

> > The stylesheet https://raw.github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/master/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css". @ http://jsbin.com/oyiceq/1/edit

Don't use the resource from github - it's not a CDN.  Save the file and serve it up from your own server.

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/95) on this behavior.  The relevant bit is the response from github:

> > "That's a feature, sorta. Please do not abuse the raw URLs like that, they are a very expensive operation for our servers. You should host files like that on pages.github.com instead."

Comment: Works in Chrome though. Weird looks like it doesn't care

Comment: @Trekstuff I think the Chrome code allows you to use files of the `text/plain` format, since it probably assumes it's a `.css` file because of the extension. Chrome has a lot of those features. [This topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text) is about JavaScript, but it confirms my suspicions about how it interprets files (I am not 100% sure though, it's a guess).

Comment: Doesn't work in my version of Chrome.  Many browsers will use it just fine.  Also, the fact that it works from time to time is **not** a feature... it's a quirk.  It probably has more to do with the fact that the resource is being used in a `<link rel="stylesheet"` than a file name extension.  Context over names, almost always.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks. I am getting closer. I set up a git hub pages version of project and synced everything over.  However the URL: https://raw.github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/gh-pages/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css gives me the same error. Mime type is still coming back as "text/plain", not "text/css". Any ideas?

Comment: You should *not* be using the raw.github.com URL.  That server delivers everything as `text/plain`.  Use your GitHub page URL.

Comment: @Dennis but the project URL https://github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/blob/gh-pages/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css returns a git hub page and won't work.

Comment: @Dennis Brilliant. My problem was I was using https. It will only work with http.

Answer (score 3):

The server is sending the file with the `Content-Type` of `text/plain`, which will likely prevent it from being used as CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the attribute id from your h1 tag to work. There is no #title selector in your CSS file there.

Comment: The `id` attribute does not prevent styling via non-id selectors unless there is a specificity conflict (and there isn't in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Use relalative paths, the link you used leads to a page *showing* the CSS, but not actually serving the data as CSS.

Comment: This is not true.  The link works fine, and returns raw CSS.  The only thing wrong with it is the `content-type` header.

Comment: And the header is not set to CSS as the file is not used for serving CSS, but to view the CSS. You cannot change the header yourself in github in this situation.

Answer (score -2):

I checked the css file and you don't have any **title** id. You have set the style on the **h1** element. So in order to see the style, you can choose to modify the HTML like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic JavaScript Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.github.com/dublintech/JavaScript_Examples/master/jsquiz/css/jquiz.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please be styled</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

or modify the css like this:

```
#resultsTable {
   width:100%;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
#resultsTable td, #resultsTable th 
{
font-size:1em;
border:1px solid #0066CC;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#resultsTable th 
{
font-size:1.1em;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#A7C942;
color:#ffffff;
}
#resultsTable tr.alt td 
{
background-color:#e7f4c3;
}


body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #669966;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma;
}
.questionContainer {
    width: 800px;
    border: 3px double #003366;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 10px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    background: none;
}
.btnContainer {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 2%;
}
#progressKeeper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 3px double #003366;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 3px;
}
#txtStatusBar {
    margin: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#progress {
    background: green;
    width: 0;
    height: 25px;
}
.radius {
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
}
#resultKeeper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 3px double #003366;
    background:#66CC66;
}
#resultKeeper div {
    line-height: 20px;
}
.totalScore {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:10px;
}
input {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
#title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #003366;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
.prev { float: left; }  /** elements after a float will flow around it **/
.next, .btnShowResult { float: right; }
.clear { clear: both; }    /** no floats allowed left or right **/
.hide { display: none; } 
.resultlist  li.altli{background:#CCFFAA;}
.resultlist li {background: #BBEEAA;}
#resultsTable td.fail{color:red;}
```

Comment: The CSS does have style set on the `h1`.

Comment: so you mean that the style is given by h1 and the title id that isn't defined in the css is ignored. Right? @Brad

Comment: IDs are used for more than CSS.  The `id` attribute isn't ignored... it just has no style defined for it.  The tag will take the style defined by the `h1` element selector.