# Make IE7 load javascript first then call function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

IE7 gives the following error: 'myapp' is undefined

```
//home.html
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="//www.mysite.com/myjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    new myapp.myfunc();
</script>
```

javascript file:

```
//myjs.js
myapp = {
    myfunc : function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
};
```

*I understand there are many ways to rewrite the code that is used on home.html, but I want to make this work without changing that. I found a working example with similar structure and no JS errors (IE7, IE6). https://google-developers.appspot.com/custom-search-ads/docs/sample

EDIT:
The < script > code will be given to external clients, so I want to keep it as simple as possible. See example link.

Comment: Where is the code going to be used? Different environments? Can I paste it into my Wordpress blog? If the answer is 'I don't know' or 'Yes' to the last question, you will probably need something more robust - because loading javascript cross-browser in a reliable fashion is not simple.

Comment: @JonJaques yes, the code will be used into different environments, including copying-pasting into any blog. I've been running into all kinds of issues with cross-origin resource sharing and now some more with older IE browsers. I think what is currently the most backwards-compatible is injecting Javascript into an iFrame. I know its hacky but as long as it works it's worth a try.

Comment: So is your application trying to request additional resources once the main script comes back? Like JSON etc?

Comment: yes, I was initially looking at requesting xml data, but due to cross-origin compatibility issues I'm now looking at JSONP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) suggests that either IE/MSHTML does not support `script` elements with `type="application/x-javascript"`. That might have to do with the fact that [`application/x-javascript` is not a registered MIME media type, nor was it ever necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227303/855543).

Or it has to do with the fact that `//www.mysite.example.com/myjs.js` is not a supported [URI-reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) in that environment.  Use fully-qualified URIs like `http://www.mysite.example.com/myjs.js` instead.  (And please use the registered example domains for examples.)

You should also declare identifiers that you intend to use as variables:

```
var myapp = {
  …
};
```

If you do not do this, problems can occur if there is an element named `myapp` in the document.  In JScript/MSHTML, identifier resolution will find a host object in the scope chain that has `myapp` as its property.  The value of that property will be a reference to the corresponding element object, and attempting to overwrite that property value will cause a runtime error.

Comment: IE6 seems to dislike the application/x-javascript type. I've made some changes and that seems to work without undefined errors. I hope IE7 behaves the same way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Add an event handler to the [body's `Load` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). In that event handler, make your `myapp.myfunc()` call.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably have to do that, however I wanted to see if I could keep the client's copy/paste code to a minimum, like the example link.

Comment: What if the end user doesn't have control over the <body> html? What if it's within a content management system?

Comment: @JonJaques First of all, take W3Schools (!= W3C) with a handful of salt. As to your question, I would say then that CMS is deeply flawed. You can rely on the fact, for historical and HTML Specification reasons, that the `onload` attribute of the `body` element works. You cannot rely on that `window.onload` & friends work the same.

Comment: @PointedEars, That's why I'm not referencing any W3Schools material. The point is, if you put an html script tag in a document, then immediately try to reference the content from said tag is not going to work because scripts load asynchronously. Furthermore, I don't understand how the OP's code works anyways, because you can't use the new keyword in conjunction with an object literal.

Comment: @JonJaques You are mistaken. 1. Client-side scripts are never loaded asynchronously when included in that fashion; that is why [stylesheets should come first in a document](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PutStylesBeforeScripts) (I would not sign the other tips there, but this one is good). 2. The OP is not instantiating the `Object` instance, but the method of the object; every `Function` instance can be called as a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you're making your code available for consumption, you always want to make sure you're being a good citizen on the page. That means you don't want to create unnecessary global variables, and make sure ones you do create are unique enough. Thats why it's a good idea to wrap your code in an immediately-invoked function expression.

Also, it's generally just easier to do the whole thing with javascript. This is how Google analytics and Facebook plugins load their code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var loadScript = function(src, callback) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    // modern browsers
    script.onload = callback;
    // IE 6 & 7
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
        callback();
      }
    }
    head.appendChild(script);
  };
  loadScript('path/to/myscript.js', function() {
     //script loaded
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. I will likely need to modify the client code to assure the JS loads first then executes the function.

Comment: While you give some good suggestions (and some bad ones), you are not actually answering the question.

Comment: @PointedEars Care to elaborate on the bad ones? I will admit, I interpreted the OP's question wrong initially.

Comment: Sure. Due to lack of original research (AFAIK), I am not yet convinced that loading scripts in that fashion is a reliable approach. I know that many people do that (and JSX:dom.js contains a `loadScript()`), but, to paraphrase Bertrand Russell, “everyone can still be wrong.” Also, you are relying on proprietary features, `onload`, and `onreadystatechange`. For what?