# What is the best way to have all Backbone templates in a single JS file so that it can be put on CDN?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, underscore.js

I would like to have all Backbone templates in a one single JS file so that I can easily distribute it through CDN. Ideally it should also work with Rails asset compile workflow.

**Possible solution #1:**

A single JS file with all the templates declared as such:

```
app.templates.view = " \
<h3>something code</h3> \
";
```

Too messy. Lack of highlighting.

**Possible solution #2:**

A single html file with all the templates inline. Include the partial in my master document.

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-item">
    <li><%= item %></li>
</script>
```

I cannot use the benefit of minified JS file that is distributed through my CDN. The templates will be inline with my HTML file.

**Possible solution #3:**

Use Require.js but it does not seem to solve the need of including all templates in a single JS file.

Comment: what about something like this grunt-task? https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin but that wouldnt work with the rails asset pipeline...

Comment: ["The **source** property is available on the compiled template function for easy precompilation."](http://underscorejs.org/#template) so you could easily precompile your Underscore templates into a single JavaScript file.

Comment: you can use grunt to generate module from html template,concat and compress the template js files. you can look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923592/backbone-requirejs-html-files-loaded-with-requirejs-are-interpreted-as-js-fil/14971014#14971014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I ended with with Possible solution #2 where I have a bunch of templates and included in a master file using Rails partial. For now there are no much benefit in distributing the templates through CDN.

*I did not choose to use Grunt because I think it adds additional complexity in the workflow, considering that all devs in the team have to adopt the new workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Lineman](https://github.com/testdouble/lineman).  It gives you a really nice workflow for developing JavaScript clients.  It is really just a collection of Grunt tasks aggregated into a super-simple workflow.  One of the things it does is compile all of your Underscore (or Handlebars) templates into JSTs (like Rails).  It uses "grunt-contrib-jst" to do this and outputs the templates to "generated/template/underscore.js".  It then compiles all of your JS into a single file, though you could easily bring in the .js files separately.

It might point you in the right direction.