# Website optimization and random javascript errors in google chrome console

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, caching, optimization

I've really big problem with my website: http://ap.v11.pl/sklep/
It loads really slow and I dont know how to fix that.

I've getting some weird errors from Chrome console: http://scr.hu/0an/xq5bz
There errors are random, for example i'm getting error that something cant be found but this resource exists and the paths are good.

My htaccess:
http://pastebin.com/ewZZBLFg

Page is working on ZendFramework 2

Thank you for any advices

Comment: just a guess: did you check the problem on another computer? Eventually you have a virus which is manipulating your browser?

Comment: you say that there is no problem on your pc? The website is slow on any pc i tested it on

Comment: did you make progress?

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis is:

1. you are running Ghostery as Chrome plugin or something similar so that e.g. your browser will block a couple of your scripts like the adstat thing and google analyticis
2. your webserver has a problem sending the correct mime type for the javascript stuff. Check out this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text) on the "resource interpreted as a ..." error message

It may be that only one frontend is not working correctly. This would explain why you get the errors not all the time.

In general your site is packed with scripts and images. The first page has > 250 requests & almost 4 Mb. That's very much and it takes time. Amazon's Frontpage has half the number of requests and something like 300kb.

You should check if you can reduce the number of requests - the yslow plugin may give you some good advise here. Can you reduce the image size and number of image? (css sprites?)

You should also check if you have to deliver all the images through your regular web browser or if you can use a  lightweight alternative. Are you using NGINX? AFAIK it has good options for performance tunings.

Edit: As a starting point: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.ap.v11.pl/fBGKScZ6