# Apache conflicts with MIME types after upgrading from PHP 5.5 -> 5.6

Tags: apache, warnings, mime-types, php-5.6, php-5.5

soon after PHP5.5 -> 5.6 migration i've noticed these warnings in Chrome console:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/rowling/style.css?ver=4.7.3".`

These warnings blocks loading of css, and page becomes spoiled.

I've also noticed that removing `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration from page solves the problem. But what it is all about? Why it's happening?

---

The problem exists with all files (not only css), all .jpg, .mp4 everything comes with response as `Content-Type: text/html`

`robot@iMac:~$ curl -I https://www.example.com/image.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2017 09:17:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

p.s.

Apache modules: `mod_mime` and `mod_mime_magic` are active.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylesheet transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969148/stylesheet-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found and solved the problem!

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` i've found this line
`SetHandler application/x-httpd-php`

after removing it problem was gone.

All responses works now as should! Mime types are ok.