# 307 redirect - mime type issue

Tags: javascript, redirect, mime-types

We have this authentication procees in our application that whenever the server gets a request from a client which is not authenticated  (cookie missing) it returns a 307 response and the client should be redirected to the login page (which might on another domain).

I've bumped into the following problem:

When I delete the cookie and the main index.html page is cached and I open the web page I get 307 for the first time only when a js file is requested (there is a script tag in the index.html). In this case the browser tries to redirect and I'm getting the following error:

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://win-7-64-server:8443/cas-server/login?service=http://172.30.2.25:81%2F172.30.2.25%3A8182%2Fshunra%2Fcommon%2Fjs%2Flibs%2Frequire%2Frequire.js".`

This is the original javascript url: `http://172.30.2.25:8182/shunra/common/js/libs/require.js`

Obviously I don't control the redirect. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I thought about the problem and the problem is that the browser gets 307 http code and thinks that the javascrip file was redirected while in reality we want to redirect the entire website - any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Server must issue JS mime type 'content-type:application/javascript ' see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Comment: As far as I understand the flow is as follows: the browser sends a request for java script file --> it gets a response 307 and redirecs to the given url --> this url is to a html file (the login page) so the response is an html as expected but for some reason chrome says that it expects a javascript file and I don'tknow why.