# Ajax function not sending data onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

HOW?

First of all the mistake is this one:

data: 'rate' + $('rate').val(),

what needs to get changed as you all told me right to:

data: 'rate='+rate, or data: {rate: rate},

but there is also another problem with my server settings as well which needs (I dont know the reason) an absolt URL to the php file instead a relative.

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR TIME AND YOUR KIND HELP!

---

I am having some trouble with an onclick element for a rating script. When a user clicks on one of those fields, the value should be send via an ajax post method.

```
<li id="rating-boxes-rate" onclick="rateFunction(1)"></li>
<li id="rating-boxes-rate" onclick="rateFunction(2)"></li>
<li id="rating-boxes-rate" onclick="rateFunction(3)"></li>
<li id="rating-boxes-rate" onclick="rateFunction(4)"></li>
<li id="rating-boxes-rate" onclick="rateFunction(5)"></li>
```

The javsscript code:

```
function rateFunction(rate){
     $.ajax({
         url: '../rate.php',                    //rate.php location in parent folder
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'rate' + $('rate').val(),
         success: function(html){
                     alert('Rating: ' + rate);          //just to check, will be deleted later
                     $('#message_success').html(html); //message div id located in my html to show the outcome
         }
     });
     return false;
}
```

At this point the alert gets shown correctly but unfortunately the data is not getting send to the rate.php which at this point is a simple echo statement for testing:

```
$rate = $_POST['rate'];
echo $rate;
```

Does anyone see where exactely my code is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think `$('rate').val()` signifies anything; and you want to pass the rate values such as - 1,2,3.. to the php.

So try this-

```
data: {
    rate: rate
},
```

instead of -

```
data: 'rate' + $('rate').val(),
```

---

On the side note, you should not use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)-

You could do it like this-

```
<li id="rating-boxes-rate" rate="1"></li>
...

<script>
 $("#rating-boxes-rate").click(function(e) {
  var rate=$(this).attr('rate');
  $.ajax({
     url: '../rate.php',                    //rate.php location in parent folder
     type: 'POST',
     data: {rate: rate},
     success: function(html){
        alert(html);
     }
 });
});
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately. I am stucking on that one for 12h now :-(

Comment: what are you getting in `html` `console.log(html)`?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: At the start of the function  alert the value of `rate`

Comment: The alert is always shown correctly with the correct values. No matter if alert is put first on top or in the success function. But is type: 'POST' here correct or do I need to change it to a JSON type? I never had any troubly when I like to submit normal ajax forms but this onclick things seems to work different.

Comment: The code works fine as tested. May be the error is in your php file (some syntax error may be). Simply write two lines in your php: `$rate = $_POST['rate'];
echo $rate;` and then try

Comment: btw: I changed my code to your suggestion to avoid unobstrosive javascript, although it looks new for me to work with variables in an html code like "rate". Your code works as well as my original code. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Make passing of `data` a `json`.

```
data: {
    rate : rate
}
```

note that it's always `key` then `value`

eg

```
<input type="text" id="foo_bar" />

data : {
    foo : "bar",
    foobar : $("#foo_bar").val()
}
```

then in your PHP

```
$foo = $_POST["foo"]
$foobar = $_POST["foobar"]
echo $foo; // shows bar
echo $foobar; // shows the value of the text box
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this -

```
function rateFunction(rate){


        $.ajax({
            url: '../rate.php',                    //rate.php location in parent folder
            type: 'POST',
            data: { rate : rate},
            success: function(html){
                 alert('Rating: ' + this_rate);          //just to check, will be deleted later
                 $('#message_success').html(html); //message div id located in my html to show the outcome
            }
        });
      return false;
}
```

Comment: can you please console log and paste what html is returned as response on success of the ajax request ??

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Comment: check this link for this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Answer (score 1):

The selector `$('rate')` is trying to find a node whose type is `rate`, which more likely doesn't exist in your markup.

Since you pass the rate as a parameter in your function, why don't you pass it directly into your ajax request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../rate.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"rate": rate},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
data
{
 rate:rate
},
```

it will work

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
data: 'rate' + $('rate').val()
```

Use

```
data: {'rate': rate}
```

or

```
data: 'rate=' + rate
```