# Cannot load javascript file

Tags: javascript

My webpage has a lot of javascript files (about 100). Evry single file is loaded fine, except of that one: `<script src="javascript/tinymce/tinymce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

When I add this line, page is loading about 5 minutes and then, tinymce is not loaded. I tried open source code of that file in browser, but tinymce.js is loading to unlimited. No errors shown.

Path to file is right, because I tried to acces other files (tinymce.dev.js, tinymce.jquery.dev.js...) and everything is loading right. File name is same as in source code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it's time to start thinking about RequireJs :)

Comment: You could try and put something simple like `console.log('tinymce.js');` in a file of that name, and see if that loads.. If it is, then may want to look at something WITHIN that file being wrong..

Comment: Can't you concatenate all that file or at least some of them? It's definitely too much.

Comment: @ElonThan I can't, because its not my site, I am only repairing some bugs. And note: after 5 minutes loading, console says: `GET http://localhost:8102/editor/javascript/tinymce/tinymce.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET localhost/:55
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "chrome-extension://bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn/js/injected.js". content.js:31
(anonymous function)`

Comment: @debute I would have thought it would be a good idea to include that information in the question...

Comment: @debute Error itself has answer

Comment: So what does it mean Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain?

Comment: Why do you have so many JS files?

Comment: Its firm project and a whole page is working on javascript. Also, other subpages are using only some od them. And also, we have overview, because I am not single one programmer on this project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, where problem was. ESET Antivirus 7 blocks internet connection and then files with size more than 256kB won't show. So, in ESET:

1. Advanced setup (F5)
2. Web and email
3. Web access protection
4. URL address management
5. And added these addresses: `*127.0.0.1*` and `*localhost*`