# Incorrect MIME type from nginx serving Mezzanine and Django-compressor minified javascript

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, mezzanine

I've deployed Mezzanine to an EC2 Ubuntu instance and am serving static assets locally with a default nginx configuration.  When logged into Mezzanine the inline editing js doesn't load properly from the minified js in the static/CACHE created by compressor.

(If I turn off compressor, everything works fine)

errors: (truncated for brevity)

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://ec2-54-187-111-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/about//plugins/inlinepopups/editor_plugin.js/". 6ec516b360b5.js:616
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ec2-54-187-111-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://ec2-54-187-111-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/about//langs/en.js/". 6ec516b360b5.js:616
```

I understand the problem as being essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text) but I'm not sure how to explicitly configure nginx to set the MIME type correctly for assets loaded from within Mezzanine's minified admin js in the compressor created CACHE ?

I'm not sure what more info to post relevant to my config - will edit post in response to comments

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your Main Nginx conf and your mime.types? Also probably a good idea to post your App specific conf as well.
Be sure to sanitize as required.

```
#example
sudo cat /etc/nginx/mime.types
sudo cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```