# asp.net mvc 3 - cross domain not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to implement cross-domain using `crossDomain=true, dataType:jsonp, contentType:text/html` in `jquery's` ajax function. But the browser throws an error showing `resource interpreted as script but transferred with mime type text/html`. I've added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in IIS custom header.

My applications is built using `ASP.NET MVC 3`. I am sending `GET` request to get the data and data is adctually an `HTML` page. I've already tested it in IE, Chrome and FF. All three browsers are throwing an error. I refered [this as a reference](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

**EDIT:**

`application/x-javascript` and `text/html` is already there as `mime type` in IIS. I set the required `header` in `jquery's`  `beforeSend`

Comment: That's not a `same-origin-policy` issue, the resource was transferred but your `contentType` is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)