# Jsp on Tomcat does not load css

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat

I'm developing a jsp page webapp with Eclipse and I run it on Tomcat 7.

In the jsp page I put this css tag:

```
<link href="../css/new_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

However when I contact via browser such jsp page the css is NOT loaded and
I found that the reason is:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
```

What should I modify?

Comment: Can you show your jsp file ?

Comment: @San Krish: It's 186 lines, pretty long... can you tell me which important parts of the page you'd like to see?

Comment: Is this the only jsp which includes the css . seems more of the server side issue

Comment: I suspect it's something related to Tomcat but I don't know what to modify

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for your stylesheet, your server is telling the browser that it is an TEXT document (Content-Type: text/plain) instead of a stylesheet (Content-Type: text/css).

please add the meta tags to your jsp,

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Language" content = "en"/>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

if you are using it in the jsp tags,

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
```

Use the Net tab of your browser's developer tools to examine the request and the response.

And read this [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)

Comment: I added in the jsp all the three tags you suggested and I also added to the web.xml but to no avail this:        <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping> and of course I restarted Tomcat...