# Cordova plugin error: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova 4 with Cross-walk and on android it throws the 'Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain' error for all plugins' javascript files.

I have already added the Whitelist plugin and added the following to my index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; script-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;">
```

and these to the config.xml

```
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)

Comment: This is not a duplicate; Cordova is often used to load local files with `file://` URLs, so configuring the server is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe those are not 'real' errors and Chrome specific: see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467430/1800695)

Comment: Yep. Also @Khashayar.P Be sure you have type="text/javascript" on your script tags. I've found that helps reduce the warnings.