# Magento 2 Wysiwyg TinyMCE editor Popups want to download htm file

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, tinymce, magento2

I am using Magento 2.

In my local and development system, wysiwyg works fine. But when I upload it to the live/client server than in the wysiwyg whenever I click on the icon for example "insert table" it starts to download the "table.htm" file.

When I try to see the console it is giving the following notice 
"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php"

One more thing live server is using the https.

I think it is an issue of server settings or .htaccess I try to apply some solutions found on the internet but none is working.

Can you please help me to identify the reason so I can ask the client to provide that permission etc on the server. Thank you.

I have found one answer related to my question. [Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text) .

So should I ask the server admin to add the type AddType text/javascript .js ?

Answer (score 1):

We need to add AddType text/html .htm in .htaccess file or mime of the apache

In .htaccess it will be

```
AddType text/html .htm
```